# React input when focus

Tags: reactjs

Just starting react and trying to follow [Kirupa](https://www.kirupa.com/react/simple_todo_app_react.htm)

When i click on submit button after entering some values to the input, all working good, but when i enter some value and hit keyboard enter i have some errors like : f

```
onloadwff.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at setFieldValue (onloadwff.js:71)
at HTMLFormElement.formKeydownListener (onloadwff.js:71)
```

From console, all still working but i don't know why the error.

Thanks for your helps guys

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your input tag:

```
onKeyDown={() => event.keyCode === 13 ? this.addItem : ''}
```

(13 is the keycode for enter)

This will bind the enter event to your addItem func. I don't like to use submit buttons in forms because of this. It's way easier to store your input info in some state, then send the state value (for me, it's less buggy and more straightforward).